# Containment of $c_0$ or $\ell_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence of unit vectors in a Banach space $X$ such that $$\mbox{dist}(x_m, S_{X_n})=1$$

for all $m > n$. Here $S_{X_n}$ stands for the unit sphere $\mbox{span}\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. Can we conclude that $X$ contains an isomorphic copy of $c_0$ or $\ell_p$?

This question is motivated by the observation that the canonical bases of $c_0$ and $\ell_p$ have this property. I cannot think of any other example of a Banach space with this property.

Comment: Doesn't the same also hold for $\ell^2$, where $(x_n)$ is the standard basis? More generally, it should hold for every $\ell^p$ space with the standard basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can find such a sequence in any infinite dimensional normed space. See the proof of [Lemma 1.4.22](http://books.google.com/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&pg=PA33&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Megginson's An Introduction to Banach Space Theory.   But, there are infinite dimensional Banach spaces that contain neither $c_0$ nor any $\ell_p$, such as [Tsirelson's space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsirelson_space).